# How can i change Timpicker Style wheel?

Tags: android, android-view, android-theme, android-styles, android-timepicker

How can I change Timepicker Style to whee?

When I make Timepicker in my layout

like this

[image: http://d339vfjsz5zott.cloudfront.net/123_Java_Android-Date-And-Time/TimePickerDialog.png]

but I want this style

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO3Gs.png]

i know that is default style. I don't know how I can change the timepicker style

what can I do?

Comment: This style you want is a default style of android ICS version.you need to make customize date time picker wich looks exactly like ICS style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you use old api (lower than ICS 4.0). To use the new styled TimePicker import [SimonVT's TimePicker](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-timepicker) library. It has exactly the same style, that android > 4.0 TimerPicker has. It can be used starting from Android 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Use [wheel picker](https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/) library. You can style it any way you like and there is no limit to the type of content you can put in it. It's written by a Google Developer and I've used it in the past with no issues. I think it's compatible for Android 2.1+.